# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object for href

Tags: apex, sandbox

The error is coming as I know if there is a null value you are assigning. Although I have checked the null values . Below is the code :

```
for(String accValue : listStrings){
    if(accIds.get(accValue)!=null){
         String fullFileURL =System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().remove('-api' )+'/';

         system.debug('fullFileURL'+fullFileURL);
         system.debug('accValue'+accValue);
         accLinkVal.add('<a href="'+fullFileURL+accValue+'">'+accValue+'</a>');
     } 
}
```

Comment: `accValue` might be null

Comment: it is coming through for sure for first time.Might be failing in the second iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1):

`accIds` must be a map of Id to string or something along those lines. That would cause a null pointer exception whenever accValue is not found or when the key for `accIds` is null that contains `accValue`. I'll add that it's unlikely that `listStrings` would have a null value since it would be "empty" instead. Accessing that value would at worst cause a list exception, NOT a null pointer exception. The line below would cause the 1st mentioned exception:

```
accIds.get(accValue)!=null
```

Testing for `accIds.contains(accValue)` would prevent this kind of exception from being thrown.

**Edit:**

Because your error message is `Attempt to de-reference a null object for href`, that tells us one of two things. Either there's a problem with this line:

```
String fullFileURL =System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().remove('-api' )+'/';
```

or with this line:

```
accLinkVal.add('<a href="'+fullFileURL+accValue+'">'+accValue+'</a>');
```

The first would of course affect the 2nd. Except in a formula, I have never seen `remove('-api' )`. This could be the cause of your issue. Otherwise, in the last line, the `isblank` would need to be interpreted as being Null for this error to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(String accValue : listStrings){
    if(accIds.get(accValue)!=null){
            if(accIds.contains(accValue)){
               String fullFileURL =System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().remove('-api' )+'/';
               system.debug('fullFileURL'+fullFileURL);
               system.debug('accValue'+accValue);
               accLinkVal.add('<a href="'+fullFileURL+accValue+'">'+accValue+'</a>');
                } 
            }
    }
```